# Convert Pandas dataframe to Dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-conversion, dask

Suppose I have pandas dataframe as:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
```

When I convert it into dask dataframe what should `name` and `divisions` parameter consist of:

```
from dask import dataframe as dd 
sd=dd.DataFrame(df.to_dict(),divisions=1,meta=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns,index=df.index))
```

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

**Edit** :
Suppose I create a pandas dataframe like:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
```

Similarly how to create dask dataframe as it needs three additional arguments as `name,divisions` and `meta`.

```
sd=dd.Dataframe({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]},name=,meta=,divisions=)
```

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I think you can use [`dask.dataframe.from_pandas`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.from_pandas):

```
from dask import dataframe as dd 
sd = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)
print (sd)
dd.DataFrame<from_pa..., npartitions=2, divisions=(0, 1, 2)>
```

EDIT:

I find [solution](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/57285aa1cd721f0845b4f2b3756cb82d5f4597cf/dask/dataframe/tests/test_categorical.py#L14):

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.dataframe.utils import make_meta

df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})

dsk = {('x', 0): df}

meta = make_meta({'a': 'i8', 'b': 'i8'}, index=pd.Index([], 'i8'))
d = dd.DataFrame(dsk, name='x', meta=meta, divisions=[0, 1, 2])
print (d)
dd.DataFrame<x, npartitions=2, divisions=(0, 1, 2)>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want to what is name and divisions parameter, while creating dask dataframe.I have gone through the documentation but couldn't understand.

Comment: I am not `dask` expert, but I think you need [rom-raw-dask-graphs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html#from-raw-dask-graphs).But I think [author of dask](http://stackoverflow.com/users/616616/mrocklin) explain more.

Comment: Thank you I'll try to figure it out and wait for other answers.

Comment: @jezrael is correct.  You should create a Dask.DataFrame using the from-pandas method.  You only need to use the constructor in advanced situations

Comment: @MRocklin I got it but creation of dataframe in pandas is easy as mentioned in `edit` but similarly how to create a simple dataframe directly not from pandas.I asked question for pandas so @jezrael is correct but I just wanted to know creating a sample dataframe directly.

Comment: I agree, this would be interesting to know.

Comment: @MRocklin - I add solution, can you check it? Thank you.

Comment: @rey - I find solution, please check it.

Comment: @jezrael thanks for adding solution.I had searched through github dask but couldn't find it.