# Dask error when compute() is called more that one time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I'm working with `dask` and I need to perform a transformation using `compute()` before to continue the workflow. During the second transformation seems that the object change of type and is raising the error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'compute'`

My current code looks like:

```
newtypes = {"age":int, "is_superuser":bool}
df = df.astype(newtypes).compute()
# ....
# 
....
strtypes = {"age":str, "is_superuser":str)
df = df.astype(strtypes).compute() # Here is raised the exception.
```

Comment: Check ``type(df)`` it might be pandas dataframe which does not support ``compute``

Comment: You're right, it change from `<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>`  to `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`. Any idea of how to solve it ? 
I read about `delayed` but since I need to perform the transformation immediately it's not my option.

Comment: This might be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39722445/4985099

Comment: Please first consider what it is you are trying to achieve, and rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your second dataframe is actually a Pandas dataframe, not a Dask dataframe, and so you do not need to call `.compute()` the second time.