# Avoiding apply to a pandas groupby to do multifunction operation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply multiple functions to different columns in pandas. My dataframe consists of over 10M rows and over 100K groups. I'm trying to similar operations as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47103408/1059860) (Example below), but it takes a long time. I tried using [dask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39722445/1059860), but that didn't help either.

Any suggestions on how to improve this example below?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), columns=list('abcd'))
df['group'] = [0, 0, 1, 1]
def f(x):
    d = {}
    d['a_sum'] = x['a'].sum()
    d['a_max'] = x['a'].max()
    d['b_mean'] = x['b'].mean()
    d['c_d_prodsum'] = (x['c'] * x['d']).sum()
    return pd.Series(d, index=['a_sum', 'a_max', 'b_mean', 'c_d_prodsum'])

df.groupby('group').apply(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) for avoid `MultiIndex in columns` and for `c_d_prodsum` are multiple columns to helper column:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), columns=list('abcd'))
df['group'] = [0, 0, 1, 1]
df1 = (df.assign(tmp=df['c'] * df['d'])
        .groupby('group').agg(a_sum =('a', 'sum'),
                              a_max =('a', 'max'),
                              b_mean = ('b', 'mean'),
                              c_d_prodsum = ('tmp', 'sum')))

print (df1)
          a_sum     a_max    b_mean  c_d_prodsum
group                                           
0      1.323196  0.986277  0.545173     0.233486
1      1.598484  0.862159  0.256181     0.334105
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it help to aggregate them with [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), columns=list('abcd'))
df['group'] = [0, 0, 1, 1]
df['c_d_prod'] = df['c'] * df['d']


df = df.groupby('group').agg({'a' : ['sum', 'max'], 'b' : ['mean'], 'c_d_prod': ['sum'] })
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
              a                   b  c_d_prod
            sum       max      mean       sum
group                                        
0      1.693675  0.966228  0.500866  0.155463
1      0.950398  0.786002  0.355562  0.557794
```

You can rename the columns if you like:

```
df.columns = ['a_sum', 'a_max', 'b_mean', 'c_d_prodsum']
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
          a_sum     a_max    b_mean  c_d_prodsum
group                                           
0      0.899459  0.736511  0.233027     1.287123
1      0.913862  0.654808  0.730330     0.177089
```

Comment: Hmm. A negative vote with no explanation? Care to explain?

Comment: Not from me :-) I like your answer. it is simple, but jezrael answered early, so ticking his