# Read nested JSON into Dask DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dask, jsonlines

I am trying to read nested JSON into a Dask DataFrame, preferably with code that'll do the heavy lifting.

Here's the JSON file I am reading:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "name": "george",
        "age": 16,
        "exams": [{
                "subject": "geometry",
                "score": 56
            },
            {
                "subject": "poetry",
                "score": 88
            }
        ]

    }, {
        "name": "nora",
        "age": 7,
        "exams": [{
                "subject": "geometry",
                "score": 87
            },
            {
                "subject": "poetry",
                "score": 94
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Here is the resulting DataFrame I would like.

| name | age | exam_subject | exam_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| george | 16 | geometry | 56 |
| george | 16 | poetry | 88 |
| nora | 7 | geometry | 87 |
| nora | 7 | poetry | 94 |

Here's how I'd accomplish this with pandas:

```
df = pd.read_json("students3.json", orient="split")
exploded = df.explode("exams")
pd.concat([exploded[["name", "age"]].reset_index(drop=True), pd.json_normalize(exploded["exams"])], axis=1)
```

Dask doesn't have `json_normalize`, so what's the best way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2):

If the file contains json-lines, then the most scale-able approach is to use [`dask.bag`](https://examples.dask.org/bag.html) and then map the `pandas` snippet across each bag partition.

If the file is a large json, then the opening/ending brackets will cause problems, so an additional function will be needed to remove them before mapping the text into json.

Rough pseudo-code:

```py
import dask.bag as db

bag = db.read_text("students3.json")

# if there are json-lines 
option1 = bag.map(json.loads).map(pandas_fn)

# if there is a single json
option2 = bag.map(convert_to_jsonlines).map(json.loads).map(pandas_fn)
```

Comment: I couldn't quite get this working, probably cause I'm unfamiliar with the bag API.  Take a look at my answer and let me know what you think!

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.json_normalize`

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('students3.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

df = pd.json_normalize(data['data'], record_path='exams', meta=['name', 'age'])
```

```
    subject  score    name age
0  geometry     56  george  16
1    poetry     88  george  16
2  geometry     87    nora   7
3    poetry     94    nora   7
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get this to work with Dask?

Comment: @Powers Sorry, didn't notice that it is dask, how about https://stackoverflow.com/q/39721800/10315163?

Answer (score 1):

[Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#dictmodel-and-iteration) offers excellent JSON validation and ingest. Several Pydantic models (one of each 'top level' JSON entry) can be converted to Python dictionaries in a loop to create a list of dictionaries, type: List[Dict], which may be converted to DataFrame objects.

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by the other answers to come up with this solution.

```
ddf = dd.read_json("students3.json", orient="split")

def pandas_fn(df):
    exploded = df.explode("exams")
    return pd.concat(
        [
            exploded[["name", "age"]].reset_index(drop=True),
            pd.json_normalize(exploded["exams"]),
        ],
        axis=1,
    )

res = ddf.map_partitions(
    lambda df: pandas_fn(df),
    meta=(
        ("name", "object"),
        ("age", "int64"),
        ("subject", "object"),
        ("score", "int64"),
    ),
)
```

`print(res.compute())` gives this output:

```
     name  age   subject  score
0  george   16  geometry     56
1  george   16    poetry     88
2    nora    7  geometry     87
3    nora    7    poetry     94
```

Comment: This looks good! My only reservation: this will be memory intensive for large json files (forcing one partition per file, see [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_json.html#dask.dataframe.read_json)). So if you have a lot of small files, then your approach will work great, if the files are larger than memory, it might not work... The bag approach gives finer-grain control over size of partitions, but requires a bit of a hack to turn json into json-lines...